# Using WAMP, localhost loads the site fine, 127.0.0.1 site shows messed up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, localhost, wamp, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am very much confused. I use WAMP on Windows 7 x64. I am working on a project with Twitter Bootstrap 3 and I use `http://localhost:8080/project` to view it.

The other day I moved the project online at `http://example.com/project`, only to see the formatting broken, I was being served something that looked like a mobile version of the site.

If I view my project by `http://127.0.0.1:8080/project`, site is also broken. But `http://localhost:8080/project` looks fine.

It's html+css(Bootstrap) and a bit of js and php.

I haven't found a similar issue so far, please help!

Comment: So site show fine on localhost, but not on a domain or from 127.0.0.1,  can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used absolute path`(http://localhost:8080/project/files)` anywhere to load the CSS and JS files?If yes, I think that's causing the problem. Make sure to use relative path to load resources.

That way you can deploy your app anywhere without changing the paths in your HTML files.

Comment: I checked and double checked, relative paths everywhere. Even more.. this happened when migrating from Bootstrap 2 to 3, the site was working fine.

Comment: I think there is issue with **$website_url** variable. Can you cross check what value has been assigned to it?

Comment: Indeed, this was the issue! `$website_url` was pointing to `http://example.com` or if `localhost` to `http://localhost:8080/project`. I made the changes. Thank you very much!